# Redirecting to another page using C# Response.Redirect in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I hava an aspx page and I need to response.redirect to the same page. I am doing while clicking on a button. Can i possible to do it in javascript.

I tried `window.location=url;` . I want to know how `<% Response.Redirect(url) %>`can be called in javascript?

Comment: You can't use `Response.Redirect` from client-side JavaScript - what's wrong with `window.location`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To redirect in javascript you need to use the `window.location` property:

```
window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/test.aspx") %>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect` cannot be called in Javascript, that is a server side bit of code. `window.location` does effectively the same job.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, where you declare your button, add this.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="window.location(YOUR REDIRECT URL)" />
```